# Usage Windows Internal Database

Tags: database, window

Is possible use the Windows Internal Database to store my application registers?

Example: Store users, events, products....

Is that a bad practice?

Comment: Yes, it is a bad practice.

Comment: "It is designed to only be accessible to Windows Services running on the same machine."